# RegEx can someone help me only get the content inside (# CONTENT #)

Tags: regex

Here is a link to how far I have gotten to now:
https://regexr.com/3papp

Test text: // # DECLARE SESSION VALUES #

I only want (DECLARE SESSION VALUES), not the # or //

I have tried positive lookback, but I cannot use it in coffeescript. It just give an error, and every other solution I have found always returns the value with # at the beginning and end.

For the person who marked this as a duplicate, this is a screenshot of the result:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/KzXt9Pt]

I have already tried this.

Comment: Just grab `match[1]`

Comment: Try this `text.match(/(?:#).*(?:#)/g)`.

Comment: There is no lookbehind in JS. So, you don't need it anyway `#(.+?)#` and it's there in capture group 1. Or, don't I understand the question ?

Comment: The result i get is (# DECLARE SESSION VALUES #), and i only want (DECLARE SESSION VALUES)